# Get Google Plus friend list using Google + API / Google People API iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-api, google-plus, google-people-api

I'm trying to retrieve the list of friend list using Google + API. but it returns an empty list every time. Have they disabled it? Used https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/list?authuser=0#examples to test this.

Since The Google+ People API list endpoint is deprecated, I tried to use Goggle People API. But it returns the whole contact list (not Google + friend list). Also without the email addresses of the contacts. Tried with, https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list?authuser=1

(If we can not get only the Google + friend list then I can show all the contact list instead of Google + friend list. But I need to get the email addresses of the contacts.)

Can someone please help.

Comment: As you said its deprecated https://developers.google.com/+/web/people/#retrieve-a-collection-of-people.   did you try the profile scope?

Answer (score 0):

the People.list endpoint itself, has been deprecated:

> The Google+ People API list endpoint has been deprecated. In the past,
>   the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login scope allowed access to
>   a list of people in the user's circles in addition to their name and
>   profile information. Starting in September 2016, new grants of the
>   plus.login scope will allow access to only the user's name and profile
>   info; calls to the API return empty circle data for those new
>   sign-ins. In 2017 Q1, you will get empty circle data back for all
>   users.

https://developers.google.com/+/web/people/#retrieve-a-collection-of-people